# Как в react-router избавиться от хэша в url?

Tags: reactjs

Сейчас в приложении перейдя по адресу

```
http://localhost:63342/bootstrap-router-flux/public/index.html#/about
```

в строке url можно увидеть что-то типа этого:

```
http://localhost:63342/bootstrap-router-flux/public/index.html#/about?_k=ctfi79
```

Как настроить роутер так, что бы этот хэш не отображался?

Comment: Подробно вопрос рассмотрен [здесь](https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/react-router-course-ru/content/browserhistory_vs_hashhistory.html)

Answer (score 2):

Использовать

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    {/* ... */}
<Router>
```

Вместо

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    {/* ... */}
<Router>
```

Можно про это вот [здесь](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/blob/start/lessons/10-clean-urls.md) подробнее почитать